# Web Audio - decodeAudioData

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, sox, web-audio-api

I'm grabbing g711 a-law packages from an RTP-Stream (walky talky). My goal is to convert g711 to wav or wavpcm to send this chunks via websockets to the browser.
This is my sox command line:

*sox --channels 1 --type raw --rate 8000 -e a-law snd.in --type wavpcm --rate 8000 -e signed-integer -b 32 snd.out*

When I'm sending this packages (not a compleate file) via websocket (binary - ArrayBuffer) to the browser and try do "decodeAudioData", I always get exception "unable to decode audio data".

What audio conversion has to used (sox parameter) that AudioContext.decodeAudioData can work with?

many thanks in advance

Harry